# ASP.NET MVC URL parsing issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, asp.net-mvc-routing

Why does MVC URL parsing logic ignore some function-looking strings injected into an URL?

e.g. https://www.asp.net/(A(bcd))/downloads IS THE SAME AS https://www.asp.net/downloads

Injected sequence is "(A(bcd))", where:

- A - should be exactly one upper-case char
- bcd - can be arbitrary string

Moreover, if you use UrlHelperExtensions.Action(...) method to generate new URL based on a request with injected string, the newly generated URL will contain the same injected string.

Any insights?